# Sibling UIViewController Navigation

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

would anybody care to comment on this piece of code?

It allows you to do "prev" or "next" once in the detail view of a uiviewcontroller.

So, if you have 4 uiviewcontrollers, you can navigate from #3 to #2 with previous or #3 to #4 with next.  It works, but, my question is, is this the best way to implement this? or, is there a better way.

http://github.com/joop23/UIViewController

Answer (score 0):

You might take a moment to read the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/NavigationControllers/NavigationControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH103-SW12) before making your own navigation code. The [`-setViewControllers:animated:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/setViewControllers:animated:) method addresses rearranging or moving within the navigation stack.

Comment: i was just trying to implement the same functionality found in "Gas Cubby" app.  The also have the prev and next.  My approach does the same thing but I was wondering if there was a better way to acheive this.